# R 'differing number of rows' error using OpenWeather API

Tags: r, api

For an assignment I'm trying to fetch weather forecast data from the [OpenWeather API](https://openweathermap.org/api). My code returns this error:

```
Error in data.frame(city = city, weather = weather, visibility = visibility,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 40, 1, 0, 12
```

I clicked to re-run with RStudio's debug and got:
[image]

Not sure what's causing this error. Can anyone help me find the problem in my code? Very grateful for any help.

```
# To create empty vectors to hold data temporarily

city <- c()
weather <- c()
visibility <- c()
temp <- c()
temp_min <- c()
temp_max <- c()
pressure <- c()
humidity <- c()
wind_speed <- c()
wind_deg <- c()
forecast_datetime <- c()
season <- c()

# To get 5-day forecast data for select cities
get_weather_forecast_by_cities <- function(city_names){
  df <- data.frame()
for (city_name in city_names){
  url_get='https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast'
  weather_api_key <- "[*my API key*]"
  forecast_query <- list(q = city_name, appid = weather_api_key, units="metric")
  response <- GET(url_get, query=forecast_query)
  json_list <-content(response, as="parsed")
  results <- json_list$list
  
  for(result in results) {
    # Get weather data and append them to vectors
    city <- c(city, city_name)
  }
  
    # Combine into a DF
    weather <- c(weather, result$weather[[1]]$main)
    visibility <- c(visibility, result$visibility)
    temp <- c(temp, result$main$temp)
    temp_min <- c(temp_min, result$main$temp_min)
    temp_max <- c(temp_max, result$main$temp_max)
    pressure <- c(pressure, result$main$pressure)
    humidity <- c(humidity, result$main$humidity)
    wind_speed <- c(wind_speed, result$wind$speed)
    wind_deg <- c(wind_deg, result$wind$deg)
    forecast_datetime <- c(forecast_datetime, result$dt_text)
    months <- as.numeric(format(as.Date(forecast_datetime), '%m'))
    index <- setNames(rep(c('winter', 'spring', 'summer', 'fall'), each=3), c(12,1:11))
    season <- unname(index[as.character(months)])
    
    weather_df <- data.frame(city=city, weather=weather, visibility=visibility, temp=temp, temp_min=temp_min, temp_max=temp_max, pressure=pressure, humidity=humidity, wind_deg=wind_deg, forecast_datetime=forecast_datetime, months=months, index=index, season=season)
  
        }
  
  return(df)    
  
}

cities <- c("Seoul", "New York City", "Paris", "London", "Taiyuan")
cities_weather_df <- get_weather_forecast_by_cities(cities)
```

Comment: The first thing you should do to debug something like this is to look at the data before trying to put it into a data frame, since data frames are more strictly structured. Have you looked at the structure of `results`? You also shouldn't post an API key here unless it comes from a public demo

Comment: Thanks for your response, camille. I've redacted my API key, having completely forgotten to do so earlier.

Comment: You should link to specifically which API you're working with so we know the specifics of it—Open Weather Maps has dozens of endpoints—is [this](https://openweathermap.org/forecast5) the one you're using it?

Comment: Respectfully, isn't that specified in my code: url_get='https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast'

Comment: Yeah that's the endpoint, but in order to get any of the documentation for that endpoint I had to look through the list of 30is APIs to find which one that's the URL for. It's helpful to link to a source of more information for an API. What's the output you're trying to get exactly? The response is a nested list, and it's unclear what you're trying to get as your data frame columns. Like which of the values in the `weather` list do you actually want as columns?

Comment: Thanks for your patience, camille. This is the first time I've imported from an API. Our instructor only gave us the api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast. Here's [the link to the 5 day forecast API](https://openweathermap.org/forecast5). My understanding is that we are to write one code that will import the desired data for all five cities at once. Desired columns are: weather; visibility; temp; temp_min; temp_max; pressure; humidity; wind_speed; and wind_deg.